# Dll with same class name

Tags: c#, dll

I have created an external dll that have as class name: `User`. I imported it in another program, this have the same class name `User`. Now if I type: `User.` for access to the method of dll, the intellisense instead show me the method of the class `User` of my own program of course. A practice example:

**[DLL]:**

```
public class User{
  ... some method ...
}
```

**[Program that implement dll]**

```
using User;

public class User{

      public void getUsers(){
            User. //can't access to dll method
      }
}
```

Any idea to fix this? Please note that the namespace are different.

Comment: Are also the namespaces equals?

Comment: No, the namespace is different

Comment: I suspect you want `global::User`, but it's not entirely clear - we also don't know why you've put `User` in backticks in the class declarations...

Comment: So use the full namespace of the DLL class

Comment: If the namespaces are different, then please tell us about that. Ideally, give us a short but *complete* example, rather than just snippets.

Comment: @JonSkeet Typo error in the example.

Comment: But still no sign of a namespace in the sample... I can't overstate how much more useful and answerable a question with a complete example is.#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell from your example, but it looks like what you want is an **extern alias directive**.  You can read a short tutorial on them here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ansonh/2006/09/27/extern-alias-walkthrough/

And the documentation for the command line form is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx

Let's suppose your DLL assembly is Foo.DLL.  So what you would do is, first **add an alias** to the referenced Foo.DLL, call the alias "Foo". Second, add a directive to your namespace directives:

```
extern alias Foo;
```

Then in your program you can say  `Foo::User` and the compiler will know that you mean the `User` from `Foo.DLL` and not the one from the current compilation.

Comment: Got it, so this alias should be added in the sofware that use the dll? It's not possible do this operation in the dll itself?

Comment: @IlDrugo: Well looking at your comments, it looks like the User class in the DLL is in a different namespace than the one in the new compilation. So in that case I would just fully qualify the usage with the namespace.

Comment: Or use an alias if it's going to be used often: `using MyUser = MyNamespace.User;`

Answer (score 2):

Use the full namespace of your DLL to call `User` class. Something like this:

```
YourClassLibrary1.User user = new YourClassLibrary1.User();
user.getUsers();
```

Or by using an alias like this:

```
using DLLUser = ClassLibrary1.User;
```

Then:

```
DLLUser user = new DLLUser();
user.getUsers();
```

Comment: This actually solve the problem, access by the namespace. But is a good solution? There is another way to access directly to the class dll name?

Comment: @IlDrugo...Yes by adding it to your using directive but since you have two class with same name it refers to one in your main project so you have to either use the full namespace of your DLL or use an alias.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an alias in your code:

```
using MyUser = User;

public class User{

      public void getUsers(){
            MyUser.User.<any property or public method>
      }
}
```