# How to resolve the class name conflict problem in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

I use a third party dll which does not use namespace, it contains a enum named `Speaker`.

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: Speaker
// Assembly: StreamSDK, Version=1.0.6782.19546, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: 82353EB3-505A-4A47-8EEB-ED74ED4FC9B9
// Assembly location: /Users/haha/test/Assets/_ThirdParty/SteamSDK/Core/XMLSerializer/StreamSDK.dll

public enum Speaker
{
  remote,
  local,
  none,
}
```

My local project also has this class name under a specified namespace `Photon.Voice.Unity;`. After I import the dll, error happens because the compiler treats the local `Speaker` as the third party's `Speaker`.

I already use namespace in my local project:

```
using Photon.Voice.Unity;
```

Error happens in the following codes :

```
private void OnSpeakerCreated(Speaker speaker)
{
    speaker.gameObject.transform.SetParent(this.RemoteVoicesPanel, false);
}
```

The error:

```
error CS1061: 'Speaker' does not contain a definition for 'gameObject' and no accessible extension method 'gameObject' accepting a first argument of type 'Speaker' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

After I add the full namespace, the codes are passed.

```
private void OnSpeakerCreated(Photon.Voice.Unity.Speaker speaker)
{
    speaker.gameObject.transform.SetParent(this.RemoteVoicesPanel, false);
}
```

But I don't want to do that I just want to ban the use of the third party `Speaker` in the specified cs files or any other ways that I don't need to change the current codes.

Comment: How can it use Speaker class from third party if you do not specify the "using" of it?

Comment: Because the third party DLL does not use specified namespace and it is global.So I don't need  a namespace.

Comment: _"Error happens in the following codes"_ - what's the error?

Comment: Is it an open source 3rd party?

Comment: Either remove the using statement and full qualify the namespace or alias the namespace. Something similar like `using PTN=Photon.Voice.Unity;` and later `PTN.Speaker mySpeaker;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dll with same class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698587/dll-with-same-class-name)

Comment: @SᴇM ，I have already added the error.

Comment: @Fildor No, it is not.

Comment: Too bad, so you cannot even suggest a pull-request, introducing a namespace. Do you have alternative libs you could give a try? Not using a namespace - at least to me - has some sort of bad smell.

Comment: @Fildor agree with you.

Answer (score 5):

If you are just lazy to write `Photon.Voice.Unity.Speaker` every time, you can create an alias for using a [`using` alias directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive):

```
using PhotonSpeaker = Photon.Voice.Unity.Speaker;
```

Now you can write:

```
private void OnSpeakerCreated(PhotonSpeaker speaker)
{
    speaker.gameObject.transform.SetParent(this.RemoteVoicesPanel, false);
}
```

Comment: Because the error codes are also from the third party, so I don't want to change it..

Comment: @HarlanChen Can you explain what you mean? I am not changing anything about the third party library. I am just creating an alias for `Photon.Voice.Unity.Speaker`.

Comment: the function OnSpeakerCreated is from another third party, we just want to leave it there and don't do any changes..

Comment: tbh, in that case, I'd rather put some effort in finding a replacement for that namespace-less lib than for finding a solution to the name-conflict.