# Conflicting object names within a solution

Tags: c#

I have a project that does some file and data manipulation using several classes generated from elsewhere. I'm trying to use those generated classes in one place, but I'm running into issues when I add references in `ProcessorProject` to more than one of the "Item" projects because the object names conflict with each other.

I know that this could be easily solved by wrapping the generated code within the "Item" classes in their projects' namespace, but I'm trying to avoid modifying those generated files in any way.

Is there any other way around this that I'm not thinking of?  A way to add that generated code to the project namespace without actually modifying the files themselves?  Something else?

Very simplified model:

```
ProcessorProject
  Processor.cs
       switch (color)
           case "Blue":
               BlueUtility.DoSomething();
               break;
           case "Red":
               RedUtility.DoSomething();
               break;
       
BlueItemProject
  BlueUtility.cs
     namespace BlueItem
        class BlueUtility
  BlueItem.cs [generated]
     partial class BlueItemInfo
         public ItemInfo Information
         public SomeOtherInformation MoreInformation
     partial class ItemInfo
     partial class SomeOtherInformation

RedItemProject
  RedUtility.cs
     namespace RedItem
        class RedUtility
  RedItem.cs [generated]
     partial class RedItemInfo
         public ItemInfo Information
         public SomeOtherInformation MoreInformation
     partial class ItemInfo
     partial class SomeOtherInformation
```

Comment: Is this other question what's happening to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592715/how-to-resolve-the-class-name-conflict-problem-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you have them as references you can give them an alias as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672920/two-different-dll-with-same-namespace/3672987

Comment: Also add something like this to the top of the file where you refer to them
extern alias NewAliasOfProject;
using NewAliasOfProject::NamespaceName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an alias for each reference in the References properties window.
Then on the file where you use them write something like this at the top

```
extern alias NewAliasOfProject; 
using NewAliasOfProject::NamespaceName;
```